# Batch Grab Filename and Rename

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a file with a filename like this:
Summary_20022015.xlsx

What would i like to do is to use batch file to rename.

1) FROM: Summary_20022015.xlsx

To: Summary_20150220.xlsx

2) FROM: Summary_25022015.xlsx

To: Summary_20150225.xlsx

The original is (Filename)_DDMMYYYY.xlsx

What I need is to keep the (filename) and change to YYYYMMDD instead.
Just rearranging it using the actual filename.

Results is (Filename)_YYYYMMDD.xlsx

As I have multiple files in the folder.
It would be troublesome to manually renaming all of them.

Comment: You say that you have multiple files in the folder, but you only give one example. Since changing all of the file names to the same name would break absolutely everything, that's obviously not what you want to do. Please elaborate on your problem or else we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I have edited my questions.. for more break down. hope it provides more information

Comment: Yes, that helps quite a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Although I should also point out that your examples are going from DDMMYYYY to YYYYMMDD, and if you actually do want YYYYDDMM, you should update your examples.

Comment: Haha yes its a typo mistake. I editied my questions.
YYYYMMDD is what i needed as you've mention. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked on my test files. You are going to need to set where the files are located before you run the script. Also, it may be a good idea to put an `echo` in front of the `ren` statement at the bottom before you run it so that you make sure you are getting the output that you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: While it's a good idea to never have spaces in your paths, sometimes it's unavoidable, so use quotes
:: The quotes being where they are will preserve the spaces without including the quotes in the value
set source_files="C:\path\to\where\the files\are"

:: Go into the %source_files% path, but remember where we were for later
pushd %source_files%

:: The /b option will only process the file names and not the other things that appear with dir output
:: Split each filename on underscores and periods
:: %%A is going to be the word Source and %%C is going to be xlsx
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %%A in ('dir /b') do (
    set base_date=%%B
    set date_day=!base_date:~0,2!
    set date_mon=!base_date:~2,2!
    set date_year=!base_date:~4,4!

    ren %%A_%%B.%%C %%A_!date_year!!date_mon!!date_day!.%%C
)

:: Go back to the path we were in before the script ran
popd
```

Comment: The code works great !!! Results are as expected !!
I would add " " in case if the file name has space in it to prevent syntax error. Thanks @Dark.. 

ren "%%A_%%B.%%C" "%%A_!date_year!!date_mon!!date_day!.%%C"

Comment: @marcuschan - Your file name examples had no spaces, so I wrote the code to only allow for spaces in the path to the file, since that's likely to happen. Also, if my solution worked for you, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Yes i understand. if someone else (filename) has spaces in between by adding a double quotation would be good. so regardless of (filename) it can be use. So it would be a universal usage.
Anyway really thanks. Its a live saver haha.. I have clicked the check.
Thank you once again.